# How Do I Add Page Titles To This?

Tags: php, html

So on this script I am using I want to find out if it's possible to add titles to these pages instead of displaying the index title if you look at `lines 43 - 162` I want to use something like `$pageTitle = 'Newest Confessions';` and so on but I don't know where to add it any help? I tried doing this a few times but whatever I try it doesn't work.

Just so you know the URLs look like this `/index.php?view=newest` etc...

```
  <?php
    $pageTitle = 'Site Index - Fess Up and Stay Anonymous';
        // Check if install.php is present
        if(is_dir('install')) {
            header("Location: install/install.php");
        } else {
            if(!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();

            // Logout
            if (isset($_GET['action'])) {
                $action = $_GET['action'];
                if ($action == 'logout') {
                    session_destroy();
                    header('Location: index.php');
                }
            }

            // Access DB Info
            include('config.php');

            // Get Settings Data
            include ('includes/settings.php');
            $set = mysqli_fetch_assoc($setRes);

            // Set Localization
            $local = $set['localization'];
            switch ($local) {
                case 'en':      include ('language/en.php');        break;
            }

            // Include Functions
            include('includes/functions.php');

            $msgBox = '';

            include('includes/header.php');

            // Get the Page URL
            $pageURL = "https://www.".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

            $homePage = 'true';
            $count = 0;
            if (isset($_GET['view'])) { $view = $_GET['view']; } else { $view = ''; }

            if (isset($_GET['view'])) {
                if ($view == $viewNavLinkNewest) {
                    $select = "SELECT
                                    confessId,
                                    (IFNULL(firstName, '')) AS firstName,
                                    confessText,
                                    DATE_FORMAT(postDate,'%b %d %Y %h:%i %p') AS postDate,
                                    hasImage,
                                    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(postDate) AS orderDate,
                                    isActive,
                                    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM views WHERE views.confessId = confessions.confessId ) as totalViews,
                                    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM likes WHERE likes.confessId = confessions.confessId ) as totalLikes,
                                    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dislikes WHERE dislikes.confessId = confessions.confessId ) as totalDislikes
                                FROM
                                    confessions
                            WHERE isActive = 1 ORDER BY orderDate DESC";
                    $res = mysqli_query($mysqli, $select) or die('-1' . mysqli_error());
                } else if ($view == $viewNavLinkOldest) {
                    $select = "SELECT
                                    confessId,
                                    (IFNULL(firstName, '')) AS firstName,
                                    confessText,
                                    DATE_FORMAT(postDate,'%b %d %Y %h:%i %p') AS postDate,
                                    hasImage,
                                    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(postDate) AS orderDate,
                                    isActive,
                                    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM views WHERE views.confessId = confessions.confessId ) as totalViews,
                                    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM likes WHERE likes.confessId = confessions.confessId ) as totalLikes,
                                    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dislikes WHERE dislikes.confessId = confessions.confessId ) as totalDislikes
                                FROM
                                    confessions
                            WHERE isActive = 1 ORDER BY orderDate ASC";
                    $res = mysqli_query($mysqli, $select) or die('-2' . mysqli_error());
                } else if ($view == $viewNavLinkPopular) {
                    $select = "SELECT
                                    confessions.confessId,
                                    (IFNULL(confessions.firstName, '')) AS firstName,
                                    confessions.confessText,
                                    DATE_FORMAT(confessions.postDate,'%b %d %Y %h:%i %p') AS postDate,
                                    hasImage,
                                    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(confessions.postDate) AS orderDate,
                                    confessions.isActive,
                                    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM views WHERE views.confessId = confessions.confessId ) as totalViews,
                                    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM likes WHERE likes.confessId = confessions.confessId ) as totalLikes,
                                    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dislikes WHERE dislikes.confessId = confessions.confessId ) as totalDislikes
                                FROM
                                    confessions
                                WHERE isActive = 1
                                ORDER BY totalViews DESC, orderDate DESC";
                    $res = mysqli_query($mysqli, $select) or die('-3' . mysqli_error());
                } else if ($view == $viewNavLinkLikes) {
                    $select = "SELECT
                                    confessions.confessId,
                                    (IFNULL(confessions.firstName, '')) AS firstName,
                                    confessions.confessText,
                                    DATE_FORMAT(confessions.postDate,'%b %d %Y %h:%i %p') AS postDate,
                                    hasImage,
                                    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(confessions.postDate) AS orderDate,
                                    confessions.isActive,
                                    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM views WHERE views.confessId = confessions.confessId ) as totalViews,
                                    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM likes WHERE likes.confessId = confessions.confessId ) as totalLikes,
                                    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dislikes WHERE dislikes.confessId = confessions.confessId ) as totalDislikes
                                FROM
                                    confessions
                                WHERE isActive = 1
                                ORDER BY totalLikes DESC, orderDate DESC";
                    $res = mysqli_query($mysqli, $select) or die('-4' . mysqli_error());
                } else if ($view == $viewNavLinkDislikes) {
                    $select = "SELECT
                                    confessions.confessId,
                                    (IFNULL(confessions.firstName, '')) AS firstName,
                                    confessions.confessText,
                                    DATE_FORMAT(confessions.postDate,'%b %d %Y %h:%i %p') AS postDate,
                                    hasImage,
                                    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(confessions.postDate) AS orderDate,
                                    confessions.isActive,
                                    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM views WHERE views.confessId = confessions.confessId ) as totalViews,
                                    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM likes WHERE likes.confessId = confessions.confessId ) as totalLikes,
                                    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dislikes WHERE dislikes.confessId = confessions.confessId ) as totalDislikes
                                FROM
                                    confessions
                                WHERE isActive = 1
                                ORDER BY totalDislikes DESC, orderDate DESC";
                    $res = mysqli_query($mysqli, $select) or die('-5' . mysqli_error());
                } else if ($view == $viewNavLinkRandom) {
                    $select = "SELECT
                                    confessId,
                                    (IFNULL(firstName, '')) AS firstName,
                                    confessText,
                                    DATE_FORMAT(postDate,'%b %d %Y %h:%i %p') AS postDate,
                                    hasImage,
                                    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(postDate) AS orderDate,
                                    isActive,
                                    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM views WHERE views.confessId = confessions.confessId ) as totalViews,
                                    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM likes WHERE likes.confessId = confessions.confessId ) as totalLikes,
                                    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dislikes WHERE dislikes.confessId = confessions.confessId ) as totalDislikes
                                FROM
                                    confessions
                                WHERE isActive = 1 ORDER BY RAND()";
                    $res = mysqli_query($mysqli, $select) or die('-6' . mysqli_error());
                }
            } else {
                $select = "SELECT
                                confessId,
                                (IFNULL(firstName, '')) AS firstName,
                                confessText,
                                DATE_FORMAT(postDate,'%b %d %Y %h:%i %p') AS postDate,
                                hasImage,
                                isActive,
                                (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM views WHERE views.confessId = confessions.confessId ) as totalViews,
                                (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM likes WHERE likes.confessId = confessions.confessId ) as totalLikes,
                                (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dislikes WHERE dislikes.confessId = confessions.confessId ) as totalDislikes
                            FROM
                                confessions
                            WHERE isActive = 1
                            ORDER BY confessId DESC";
                $res = mysqli_query($mysqli, $select) or die('-7' . mysqli_error());
            }

            // Get Ad Data
            $ads  = "SELECT
                        adId, adType, adImage,
                        adTitle, adText, adUrl,
                        adStartDate, adEndDate, isActive
                    FROM
                        ads
                    WHERE
                        (isActive = 1 OR
                        adStartDate <= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 0 DAY) AND
                        adEndDate >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 0 DAY)) AND
                        adType = 1
                    ORDER BY RAND()
                    LIMIT 1";
            $adres = mysqli_query($mysqli, $ads) or die('-8' . mysqli_error());
    ?>
            <section id="main-container">
                <div class="container">
                    <?php if ($msgBox) { echo $msgBox; } ?>

                    <div class="confessbox">
                        <?php
                            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
                                // Get Total Comments
                                $comssql = "SELECT 'X' FROM comments WHERE confessId = ".$row['confessId']." AND isActive = 1";
                                $commentstotal = mysqli_query($mysqli, $comssql) or die('-4'.mysqli_error());
                                $totComments = mysqli_num_rows($commentstotal);
                                if ($totComments == '1') { $comText = 'Comment'; } else { $comText = 'Comments'; }
                                if ($row['totalViews'] == '1') { $viewText = 'View'; } else { $viewText = 'Views'; }
                                $shareURL = $set['installUrl'].'page.php?page=view&confession='.$row['confessId'];
                        ?>
                                <div class="confession confHide">
                                    <p>
                                        <i class="fa fa-quote-left"></i>
                                        <?php
                                            if ($filterProfanity == '1') {
                                                echo nl2br(htmlspecialchars(filterwords($row['confessText'])));
                                            } else {
                                                echo nl2br(htmlspecialchars($row['confessText']));
                                            }
                                        ?>
                                        <i class="fa fa-quote-right"></i>
                                    </p>
                                    <input type="hidden" id="confessId" name="confessId_<?php echo $count; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['confessId']; ?>" />
                                    <div class="confession-footer">
                                        <div class="likes">
                                            <span class="label label-confess first liked">
                                                <a href="" title="Likes" id="likeIt<?php echo $row['confessId']; ?>" class="likeIt_<?php echo $count; ?> text-success">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-smile-o"></i> <span id="likesVal_<?php echo $count; ?>"><?php echo $row['totalLikes']; ?></span>
                                                </a>
                                            </span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="dislikes">
                                            <span class="label label-confess disliked">
                                                <a href="" title="Dislikes" id="dislikeIt<?php echo $row['confessId']; ?>" class="dislike_<?php echo $count; ?> text-danger">
                                                    <span id="dislikesVal_<?php echo $count; ?>"><?php echo $row['totalDislikes']; ?></span> <i class="fa fa-frown-o"></i>
                                                </a>
                                            </span>
                                        </div>
                                        <span class="label label-confess" title="Posted: <?php echo timeago($row['postDate']); ?>"><?php echo timeago($row['postDate']); ?></span>
                                        <?php if ($row['hasImage'] != '0') { ?>
                                            <span class="label label-confess"><i class="fa fa-picture-o img"></i></span>
                                        <?php } ?>
                                        <span class="label label-confess" title="Confession #<?php echo $row['confessId'] ?>">ID: <?php echo $row['confessId'] ?></span>
                                        <span class="label label-confess last" title="<?php echo $row['totalViews'].' '.$viewText; ?>"><?php echo $row['totalViews'].' '.$viewText; ?></span>
                                        <span class="label label-confess last hasVoted text-danger"><strong><?php echo $onlyVoteOnceText; ?></strong></span>
                                        <div class="comments">
                                        <a href="page.php?page=view&confession=<?php echo $row['confessId']; ?>" title="View Confession #<?php echo $row['confessId'] ?>" class="btn btn-comment btn-sm btn-icon">
                                                 View Confession
                                            </a>
                                            <a href="page.php?page=view&confession=<?php echo $row['confessId']; ?>" title="<?php echo $totComments.' '.$comText; ?>" class="btn btn-comment btn-sm btn-icon">
                                            <i class="fa fa-comments"></i> <?php echo $totComments.' '.$comText; ?>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                </div>
                        <?php
                            $count++;
                            }
                        ?>
                    </div>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-fessup btn-block" id="loadMore"><?php echo $loadMoreText; ?></a>
                    <?php
                        if(mysqli_num_rows($adres) > 0) {
                            while ($ad = mysqli_fetch_assoc($adres)) {
                    ?>
                                <div class="adText">
                                    <h3><a href="<?php echo clean($ad['adUrl']); ?>"><?php echo clean($ad['adTitle']); ?> <i class="fa fa-external-link pull-right"></i></a></h3>
                                    <p><a href="<?php echo clean($ad['adUrl']); ?>"><?php echo nl2br(clean($ad['adText'])); ?></a></p>
                                    <span class="label label-default"><?php echo $advertisementText; ?></span>
                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                </div>
                    <?php
                            }
                        }
                    ?>

                </div>
            </div>
    <?php
            include('includes/footer.php');
        }
    ?>
```

Thanks for the help everybody!

Comment: *lines 43 - 162* <- fyi this means nothing to us since we do not see line numbers in code snippets

Comment: You already set a title; you simply need to output it on the page somewhere with an `echo` (presumably in `<div class="container">`).

Comment: How do I go about doing that @Obsidian Age?

Answer (score 0):

Going from the limited information i would assume that the actual HTML header is constructed inside: `include('includes/header.php');` . 
Either way, you need to output your PHP variable to HTML:

```
...
<title><?php echo $pageTitle; ?></title>
...
```

Comment: I already have titles working for other pages just need it for those pages I just don't know how to do it.